# New column from first observation of several columns dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data and want to create the "New" variable from A, B, and C:

```
structure(list(A = c("NA", "NA", "4", "NA"), B = c("NA", "3", 
"4", "5"), C = c("1", "NA", "NA", "5"), New = c(1, 3, 4, 5)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

I just want the first non-NA observation from any of the columns
I have attempted to use `across` in dplyr but have not been able to figure out the syntax.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `pmax`:

```r
df <- type.convert(df, as.is = TRUE)
df %>% 
  mutate(New = do.call(pmax, c(across(A:C), na.rm = TRUE)))

# A tibble: 4 × 4
  A     B     C     New  
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 NA    NA    1     1    
2 NA    3     NA    3    
3 4     4     NA    4    
4 NA    5     5     5
```

Comment: It's ok.  You can keep it.  I thought it was a simpler version of mine

Comment: no problem. it make more sense to put under your answer

Answer (score 2):

We may need to first convert the `"NA"` to `NA` before extracting the first non-NA

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(New = invoke(coalesce, pick(A:C)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 4
      A     B     C   New
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    NA    NA     1     1
2    NA     3    NA     3
3     4     4    NA     4
4    NA     5     5     5
```

---

Or with `fcoalecse` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(New = fcoalesce(pick(A:C)))
```

Comment: Note that manually defining the columns, like so: `coalesce(A, B, C)` also works for a limited amount of columns

Answer (score 1):

Base R option using `apply` by selecting the first `[1]` non NA with `is.na` like this:

```r
df$New <- apply(df, 1, \(x) x[!is.na(x)][1])
df
#>      A    B    C New
#> 1 <NA> <NA>    1   1
#> 2 <NA>    3 <NA>   3
#> 3    4    4 <NA>   4
#> 4 <NA>    5    5   5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Why do you use `which()`?

Comment: @onyambu, You are right! which is not necessary.